# How to remove SOAP namespace from call

Tags: php, xml, soap

I'm trying to connect to a WSDL webservice using PHP SOAP. Now I need to remove the SOAP elements from the XML which is send. What I have now is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
               xmlns:ns1="http://service.com">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:Calculate>
        //Content
    </ns1:Calculate>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

What I want is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns1:Calculate xmlns:ns1="http://service.com">
    //Content
</ns1:Calculate>
```

Is there any way to accomplish this? Is SOAP the one I need to send such requests?

Comment: The XML that you want to create is not valid soap request xml. the original one is. You can try the original xml by replacing `SOAP-ENV` with `soapenv`. It has worked for me in the past.

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

SOAP is protocol, and if you want to SOAP request both client and server side must accept and send back requests according to this protocol.
Just check these settings :

```
$client = new SoapClient("some.wsdl", array('soap_version'   => SOAP_1_2));
```

Server may uses 1_2 or 1_1 version.
And you should contact with Web Service provider to get documentation about implementation of web service.

Answer (score 0):

Override `SoapClient` class with a customized `__doRequest`. The new method removes the namespace references from the XML then calls the parent's `__doRequest` to fulfill the request with the modified XML.  A simple but effective solution.

```
class MySoapClient extends SoapClient
{
        public function __doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way=0)
        {
             $request = str_replace('ns1:', '', $request);
             parent::__doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way);
        }
}

# Invoke derived class instead of base class SoapClient
$client = new MySoapClient($wsdl, $options);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to make a SOAP request, these tags are required. Is it really SOAP server on your opposite trying to make request?

Comment: No it's not a SOAP server, my guess it's an IIS server. The webservice doesn't understand these namespaces, so I guessed I couldn't use PHP soap.